# How can we delete database file from the users' devices?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I'm taking part in developing Android app, and I have a task to delete one useless corner. The problem is this corner has got its own database, and after deleting
the file with this db was left on the users' devices. How can I delete it from there during the next release?

Comment: `and after deleting the file with this db` How did you delete the database in code?

Comment: is it room database?

Comment: I've just deleted the corner's code. It's Room, yeap)

Answer (score 0):

For deleting data inside of firebase you can simply use

`remove()` or you can also delete by specifying null as the value for another write operation such as set() or update(). You can use this technique with update() to delete multiple children in a single API call.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll remember it!

Comment: sure, not a preasure

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of database table you may delete it by exeuting sql `drop table if exists ${table_name}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this!